# Getting state on concrete observable

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

According to [this](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) getState in only a method on the concrete observable class, not the interface. If this is true, then how does the observer know what state it can get?

Answer (score 0):

First slide is just wrong. Second slide is ok as it exposes its state through the interface.